# Faster solver - for loops

Tags: r

Say we have a cost function:

```
my_func <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11){
  rst <- (x1^2) * x2 + x2 + x3*x4*x5*x6*x7*x8*x9 + x10^3 + (1-x11-x10)
  return(rst)
}
```

The real example has same number of variables, more complex cost function.

Then say I have constraints for each variable:

```
0 <= x1 <= (1/11)
0 <= x2 <= (1/20)
0 <= x3 <= (1/5)
....
0 <= x11 <= (1/10)
```

And I want to find the minimum cost for this.

My current solution is, first building sequences for each variable, with a given accuracy (0.001), say for x1:

```
x1.seq <- seq(0, 1/11, by = 0.001)
....
```

Then I run 11 for loops, and try every combination, to try and find the minimum:

```
hold <- NULL # Preallocation of this variable does help, a bit...
for (i in 1:length(x1.seq){
  x1 <- x1.seq[i]
  for (j in 1:length(x2.seq){
    x2 <- x2.seq[j]
      ....
      hold <- c(hold, my_func(x1 = x1, ..., x11 = x11))
      ....
  }
}
min(hold)
```

Now as all of you probably know, this will run forever given the accuracy is not trivial. So is there a faster way of doing this in R? I know of other approaches like partial derivatives or Lagrange multipliers etc, but they are also time consuming (and rough with my non-liner problem), and I am looking for an R code approach, if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use some non linear optimization package:

1. `nolptr` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/index.html
2. `NlcOptim` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NlcOptim/index.html
3. `optimx`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/optimx/index.html